# Removing / extracting value from MySQL columns

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have hundreds of entries in a table called wp_postmeta.

I am focusing on two columns in wp_postmeta, 'meta_key' and 'meta_value'

Every entry where 'meta_key' is equal to '_wp_attachment_metadata', the 'meta_value' columns contain almost the exact same info:

**'meta_value'**

```
a:5:{s:5:"width";i:640;s:6:"height";i:427;s:4:"file";s:20:"2015/10/Image- 
1.jpeg";s:5:"sizes";a:2:{s:9:"thumbnail";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:20:"Image-1-
300x300.jpeg";s:5:"width";i:300;s:6:"height";i:300;s:9:"mime-  
type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:6:"medium";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:20:"Image-1-
500x427.jpeg";s:5:"width";i:500;s:6:"height";i:427;s:9:"mime-
type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}}s:10:"image_meta";a:11:
{s:8:"aperture";i:0;s:6:"credit";s:0:"";s:6:"camera";s:0:"";s:7:"caption";s:0:""
;s:17:"created_timestamp";i:0;s:9:"copyright";s:0:"";s:12:"focal_length";i:0;s:3
:"iso";i:0;s:13:"shutter_speed";i:0;s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:11:"orientation";i:0;}}
```

So basically, I want to execute something so that if 'meta_key' == '_wp_attachment_metadata' it will delete all values from 'meta_value' APART FROM the "2015/10/Image-1.jpeg" image path (first line).

The only problem is that each bit of data in the 'meta_value' is slighlty different. So 's:20:' won't always come before the image path, and ";s:5:" won't always come after, so how can I specifically extract/keep the image path value?

EDIT (EXTRA INFO): All of the image paths will include "2015" at the start, is there a way this can be used to fix my problem?

EDIT 2: I have also found that all of the image paths end with ";s:5... I should be able to use this as all image paths also start with :" before quotes

Comment: what have you tried so far? And, just for my curiosity... why you need to manipulate this way a wordpress database?

Comment: So far I haven't found anything related to what I need to do. I am transferring data from a WordPress database into my own database to be used on a mobile application. But of course my tables & column setup is different to wordpress

Comment: _“All of the image paths will include "2015" at the start, is there a way this can be used to fix my problem?”_ – it could, if you want to go about it with a regular expression, and need just the image path and nothing else. The alternative is to do it via a PHP script, and `unserialize` those values first.

Comment: Do you understand what you're doing with this string? (the fact it's a serialized data and that if you start to chunk on it you will break the length and broke it?)

Comment: So let's say for instance the image paths all start with "2015" (after opening quotes) and end with a semicolon (after closing quotes) - I still wouldn't know how to select the image path using this information.

Comment: No, vard, I'm relatively new to the world of SQL.

Comment: So to be clear about what you want to achieve, you want to delete all the attachments? Or change their name? (I mean we should do this with a proper Wordpress PHP solution instead of playing with serialized string directly)

Comment: No. I have exported the WordPress tables and imported them to my own database. I am now trying to extract the image path value from each of the attachments data, and then insert the image path into another table. So in other words, nothing is going to 'break', the database I'm editing is not linked to WordPress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright so here is a little of PHP for doing what you want to do:

```php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "db");
$rows = $mysqli->query("SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_wp_attachment_metadata'");
$image_paths = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data = @unserialize($row['meta_value']);
    if($data !== false) {
        if(isset($data['file'])) {
            array_push($image_paths, $data['file']);
        }
    }
}
// do something with your $image_paths array (like update your new DB)
```

The thing is to unserialize the data, and get the file path if it exist. You might want to check on the `mime-type` property too (`$data['sizes']['thumbnail']['mime-type']`).

Comment: vard, that is absolutely perfect! Just had to change it to use procedural MySQL. Marked you as the answer